# Using structure global variables in embeds

Tags: structure, parse-order, global-variables

I'm trying to create a navigation menu inside an embed, I have the following code in my main template:

```
{exp:structure:entries parent_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}
  {if channel_short_name == "accordion"}
  {embed="site/template_accordian"}
  {/if}
  {if channel_short_name == "album"}
  {embed="site/template_album"}
  {/if}
{/exp:structure:entries}
```

This works great, however I then have the following inside template_accordian:

```
<nav id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    {exp:structure:entries parent_id="{structure:parent:entry_id}"}
    <li><a href="#{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:structure:entries}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

{structure:parent:entry_id} doesn't seem to output anything, I'm guessing this is due to parsing order or something but can't work out how to achieve what I want to achieve, any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't need an embed when you're using structure. Is there a reason why you need to do this? What are you trying to achieve that using the structure tag isn't letting you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will work within that embed because of EE's parsing order. You may need to put it directly in the template.